# multiplying float columns in pandas takes too much time

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, floating-accuracy

Morining to all,
I have a 460.000 rows DataFrame, with 15 columns. I'm trying to assign to one column the product of another two
the code is like this

```
df[df.colx == 'S']['prd'] = df['col1']*df['col2']
```

prd, col1 and col2 have  float64 as data type.
I executed a lot of operations on other columns with no problem, including date difference, and they are almost instantly executed.
if I try

```
df['prd'] =  df['col1']*df['col2']
```

the execution is super fast. the problem raises when I try to apply the operation on a subset of the DataFrame
Someone can help me and explain how I can lower the execution time?
Thank you very much!

UPDATE:
if if do

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df[df.colx=='S'])
```

and then

```
df2['prd'] =  df['col1']*df['col2']
```

is still super slow.........
oh is it possible? df2 should be a new DataFrame.......

Comment: does it not work at all, or just takes to much time?

Comment: I tried to wait some minutes, but I've always stopped the execution because it's too much time considering that the hole code takes less than 28 seconds...

Comment: just split the operations of the subset and the multiplication: `df = df[df.colx == 'S']'` and then `df['prd']= df['col1']*df['col2']`

Comment: Thank you PV8! You solution works, but in this way I lose all the != 'S' rows..

Comment: yes, depending on the following lines, you can create a new dataframe and do not touch the original one with `df2 = df[df.colx == 'S']` and use this one then...

Comment: With the chaining indices `df[df.colx=='S']['prd'] = ...`, I'm surprised that you didn't get a warning, [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas). Consider using `.loc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to seperate the operations:

```
df2 = df[df.colx == 'S']
df2['prd'] = df2['col1]*df2['col2']
```

or if the `df.colx == 'S'`is some condition for you, you can run:

```
df['prd'] = numpy.where(df['prod'] == 'S', df['col1']*df['col2'], 'Do something else')
```

just replace Do something else with another logical opartion which should be done if `df.colx != 'S'`